# Could this well known software be a spyware?

Tags: windows, privacy, steam, spyware

[Steam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_(software)) is a digital distribution platform developed by Valve Corporation, which offers digital rights management (DRM), multiplayer gaming, video streaming and social networking services.

This program, Steam, must run a service in order to work proprely which is by default installed under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Steam\SteamService.exe". Because a service is given SYSTEM rights, any folder and file can be read and modified. And since both the service and the software itself have an access to the internet any information could be leaked at any moment. I'm very concerned about my privacy.

Comment: McAfee (and other virus or malware scanners) do much the same, scanning random files that are unrelated to its own core files and they all have access to the internet as well. By your criteria any virus protection tool is also spyware because they can ([and will](https://betanews.com/2017/10/26/kaspersky-nsa-files/)) send random files from your system to online sources without your explicit permission. The could also be uploading statistics and details of viruses and malware found. That this is *expected* is exactly the same as with Steam, where you agreed to them doing it to stop cheating.

Comment: I suspect you could have avoided the downvotes here by simply asking *why* this behaviour occurs to begin with and what purpose it serves. As it stands your question is phrased in a way that implies that you have already decided that it is in fact spyware and therefore evil and your answer only reinforces that idea. It sounds like you came to rant about the behaviour, without knowing the facts, rather than engage in constructive assessment of why it happens at all. You would have gotten the same excellent answer from gronostaj, but without the downvotes.

Comment: You cannot be sure if big name are all honest and respect your privacy. `Android` [keep tracking your location]( https://qz.com/1131515/google-collects-android-users-locations-even-when-location-services-are-disabled/) even if you turn GPS and location sharing off. Scans all your emails and text messages etc and shows ads based on your profile. `Facebook` was recently in news for sharing/spying users. Samsung smart TV [records users voice and video]( https://www.cnbc.com/2017/03/09/if-you-have-a-smart-tv-take-a-closer-look-at-your-privacy-settings.html) to show personalized ads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the nature of the question one can't give a definitive "No" answer without very time-consuming reverse engineering, but mine is:

## Probably not, and you've agreed for this suspicious behavior when installing Steam

Screenshots you've posted in your answer ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Xcw.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU7rK.jpg), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZFot.jpg)) that show Steam accessing various unrelated EXEs probably show a [VAC scan](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7849-Radz-6869). Quoting Valve, Steam's vendor:

> VAC stands for Valve Anti-Cheat, an automated system designed to detect cheats installed on users' computers. If a user connects to a VAC-Secured server from a computer with identifiable cheats installed, the VAC system will ban the user from playing that game on VAC-Secured servers in the future.
>
> The VAC system reliably detects cheats using their cheat signatures. Any third-party modifications to a game designed to give one player an advantage over another is classified as a cheat or hack and will trigger a VAC ban. This includes modifications to a game's core executable files and dynamic link libraries.

What these three programs (Procmon, Bandicam, 7+TT) have in common is that they tap into other processes.

- Procmon does deep process inspection by design
- Bandicam records screen by tapping into graphics libraries loaded by other software
- 7+TT injects its code into Windows Explorer

These are suspicious from Steam's perspective, as these actions are typical for aimbots, trainers and other software that would give you unfair advantage over other players. Steam most likely scans them to figure out whether these are unwanted and if they should punish you for using them.

It's also mentioned in the [Privacy agreement](https://store.steampowered.com/privacy_agreement/), which you have accepted when installing Steam:

> 3.9 Information Required to Detect Violations
>
> **We collect certain data that is required for our detection, investigation and prevention of fraud, cheating and other violations of the SSA and applicable laws ("Violations").** This data is used only for the purposes of detection, investigation, prevention and, where applicable, acting on of such Violations and stored only for the minimum amount of time needed for this purpose. If the data indicates that a Violation has occurred, we will further store the data for the establishment, exercise or defense of legal claims during the applicable statute of limitations or until a legal case related to it has been resolved. Please note that the specific data stored for this purpose may not be disclosed to you if the disclosure will compromise the mechanism through which we detect, investigate and prevent such Violations.

Another snippet, this time from [Subscriber agreement](https://store.steampowered.com/subscriber_agreement/#4) which you also have to accept to install Steam:

> 4. ONLINE CONDUCT, CHEATING AND ILLEGAL BEHAVIOR
>
> [...]
>
> **Steam and the Content and Services may include functionality designed to identify software or hardware processes or functionality that may give a player an unfair competitive advantage when playing multiplayer versions of any Content and Services or modifications of Content and Services (“Cheats”).** You agree that you will not create Cheats or assist third parties in any way to create or use Cheats. You agree that you will not directly or indirectly disable, circumvent, or otherwise interfere with the operation of software designed to prevent or report the use of Cheats. [...]
>
> **You may not use Cheats, automation software (bots), mods, hacks, or any other unauthorized third-party software, to modify or automate any Subscription Marketplace process.**

---

Related question on Security Stack Exchange:

> [What stops Google from saving all the information on my computer through Google Chrome?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/187556/68614)